# How to order monthname by month, not alphabeticaly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to have the results as if January is the first month in the results. Not to have it ordered alphabeticaly.

this is my query, but it has an error in the order by part:

```
SELECT datename(Month,(Orderdate)) AS Maand, 
sum(SubTotal) AS omzet , sum(Freight) AS vervoerkosten 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE Year(OrderDate) = 2012
GROUP BY datename(Month,(OrderDate))
ORDER BY Month(OrderDate) ASC
```

Comment: Side note: Something like `orderdate >= '2012-01-01' AND orderdate < '2013-01-01'` instead of `Year(OrderDate) = 2012` in the `WHERE` clause would be more index friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, use `MIN()`:

```
order by min(OrderDate) asc
```

This chooses the earliest date to define the rows.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that everything you group by needs to selected.

So you can also add the `MONTH(OrderDate)` to the GROUP BY.

```
...
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate), DATENAME(Month,OrderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)
```